# Getting Segmentation fault, during the implementation of Stack, using linked list

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, stack

In the following code, I've tried to implement the stack data structure using a linked list. Somewhere in my push function, I assume, I have implemented an improper use of pointers, since, upon execution of code, the compiler throws up a segmentation fault(core dumped)

[image]

How do I correct this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node* nextlink;
};

struct Stack
{
 int top;
 struct node* head;
 struct node* tail;
};

//creates an instance of struct Stack, and return a pointer to it
struct Stack* createStack()
{ 
  struct Stack* stack=(struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
  stack->head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));;
  stack->head->nextlink=NULL; 
}

 
// Stack is empty when head node points to null value
int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->head ==NULL;
}
```

this is my push function.

```
// Function to add an item to stack. It inserts a node between head pointer, and fist element, and initializes the node that was inserted in between before.
void push(struct Stack* stack, int item)
{
    stack->head->data=item;
    struct node* intermediate_pointer=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    intermediate_pointer->nextlink=stack->head;
    stack->head=intermediate_pointer;
    printf("%d pushed to stack\n",item);
}
```

```
// Function to remove an item from stack.  
void pop(struct Stack* stack) 
{
    if (isEmpty(stack))
     {
        printf("warning! stack is empty!\n");    
     }
     else
     {
       struct node* intermediate_pointer=stack->head;
       stack->head=stack->head->nextlink;
       free(intermediate_pointer);
     }
}
 
void print_stack(struct Stack* stack)
{
  struct node* trans_pointer=stack->head;
  while(trans_pointer!=NULL)
   {
    printf("%d",trans_pointer->data);
    trans_pointer=trans_pointer->nextlink;
   }
}
//function to respond to user's choice of operation
void stackoper_imp(int ch, struct Stack* stack)
{
  if(ch==1)
  {
   int ele;
   printf("enter the integer element you want to push on top of the stack:");
   scanf("%d",&ele);
   push(stack,ele);
   print_stack(stack);
  }
  else if(ch==2)
  {
   pop(stack);
   print_stack(stack);
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }  
}
int main()
{
  int choice;
    struct Stack* stack = createStack();
    while(choice!=3)
    {
      printf("which operation do you want to perform on your stack?\n1.push\n2.pop\n3.exit\n");
      scanf("%d",&choice);
      stackoper_imp(choice, stack);
    }

}
```

Comment: One immediate note on cursory review: `choice` in `main` is not initialized entering your `while` loop. You may want to use a `do ... while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> struct Stack* createStack()
> { 
>    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
>    stack->head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));;
>    stack->head->nextlink = NULL; 
> }
> ```

This is declared as returning `struct Stack *`, but then you don't return `stack`: the pointer to the `struct Stack` you've created.

```
struct Stack* createStack()
{ 
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));;
    stack->head->nextlink = NULL; 

    return stack;
}
```

Even with this you risk a segmentation fault as `malloc` doesn't have to succeed. You'd want to check the return value of it before trying to access member fields.

```
struct Stack* createStack()
{ 
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));

    if (!stack) return NULL;

    stack->head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));;

    if (!stack->head) return NULL;

    stack->head->nextlink = NULL; 

    return stack;
}
```

And then obviously when you use `createStack` you'll want to check to ensure it did not return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

`createStack()` does not return a pointer to the stack you created, it does not return anything.

You need to return the pointer to the stack by adding: `return stack`

```
struct Stack* stack= malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
if(stack == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for stack\n");
    return NULL;
}
struct node* head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));;
stack->head = head;
if(head == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for node\n");
    return NULL;
}
stack->head->nextlink=NULL; 
return stack;
```

Also, `malloc()` can fail, so you need to check to ensure that it does not return a `NULL` pointer as that will result in undefined behavior. However you want to handle these errors outside of the function is entirely up to you.